# Variable grouping providing different answers in optimized code

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I've been attempting to unit test a `C++` class I've written for Geodetic transforms.

I've noticed that a trivial grouping change of three variables greatly influences the error in the function.

**EDIT** : Here is the entire function for a compilable example:

Assume `latitude`, `longitude` and `altitude` are zero. `Earth::a = 6378137` and `Earth::b = 6356752.3` I'm working on getting benchmark numbers, something came up at work today and I had to do that instead.

```
void Geodesy::Geocentric2EFG(double latitude, double longitude, double altitude, double *E, double *F, double *G) {
    double a2 = pow<double>(Earth::a, 2);
    double b2 = pow<double>(Earth::b, 2);
    double radius = sqrt((a2 * b2)/(a2 * pow<double>(sin(latitude), 2) + b2 * pow<double>(cos(longitude), 2)));
    radius += altitude;

    *E = radius * (cos(latitude) * cos(longitude));
    *F = radius * (cos(latitude) * sin(longitude));
    *G = radius * sin(latitude);

    return;
}
```

Where all values are defined as `double` including those in `Earth`. The `pow<T>()` function is a recursive template function defined by:

```
template <typename T>
static inline T pow(const T &base, unsigned const exponent) {
     return (exponent == 0) ? 1 : (base * pow(base, exponent - 1));
}
```

The code in question:

```
*E = radius * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude);
*F = radius * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude);
```

produces different results than:

```
*E = radius * (cos(latitude) * cos(longitude));
*F = radius * (cos(latitude) * sin(longitude));
```

What is the compiler doing in `gcc` with optimization level `3` to make these results `1e-2` different?

Comment: use the assembler, luke. Try the gcc explorer for that. (note that I dont get different assembler for the different versions here, but ymmv)

Comment: Do you get different results when compiling w/o optimizations? If Radius is very large comapared to sin/cos range [-1,1] then expect different results

Comment: Let me make a benchmark and I'll get back to you guys

Comment: Give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please!

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is a multiplication with denormalized values making the loss of precision that huge

Comment: Are you are using single precision (float)? IEEE754 single precision is about 10^-7 relative precision. Earth Radius is about 6*10^6 m, so if you are declaring float you are in trouble, the compiler isn't.

Comment: The code still doesn't qualify as SSCCE. Apart form that, please give us the input where you experience this behavior. Without that we have no chance to reproduce it; we can only guess.

Comment: If latitude and longitude are both zero, you get exactly zero for `F` and exactly `6378137` for `E`. **You are still NOT giving us the input that produces the weird results you see.**

Answer (score 2):

You have different rounding as floating point cannot represent all numbers:

`a * b * c;` is `(a * b) * c` which may differ than `a * (b * c)`.

You may have similar issues with addition too.

example with addition:

`10e10f + 1.f == 10e10f`

so `(1.f + 10e10f) - 10e10f == 10e10f - 10e10f == 0.f`
whereas `1.f + (10e10f - 10e10f) == 1.f - 0.f == 1.f`.

Comment: This does not explain the reported behavior unless the report of 1e-2 differences is in large values (`radius` must be large). In multiplication with normal values, floating-point `(a*b)*c` produces exactly a•b•(1+e0)•c•(1+e1) for some rounding errors e0 and e1 that are at most 1/2 ULP (in round-to-nearest mode) in magnitude, while `a*(b*c)` produces exactly a•(b•c•(1+e2))•(1+e3) for some errors e2 and e3. The maximum difference between these occurs when e0 and e1 are +1/2 ULP and e2 and e3 are -1/2 ULP, and the difference will not be 1e-2 unless `radius` is large.

Comment: That could be the case if `radius` is the radius of the Earth in meters and the code is using 32-bit floating-point.

Comment: With the update to the question, we see that `radius` is 6378137 and `double` is being used. With these, the difference between `(a*b)*c` and `a*(b*c)` does not explain the observed error of 1e-2.